# Apply a macro to the selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that multiplies the contents of the selected cell by a fixed value. Each cell that I apply this to contains a formula referring to a cell in a separate sheet. The formula and cell references must remain intact, and just be multiplied by a factor.

How do I achieve this?

So far my attempts have resulted in each cell ending up with the same value (it reverts to the original cell value and multiplies that number!) or it simply appends the text of the multiplication instead of giving me a value.

This is the one I've got at the moment. It just appends the text to the end and removes the link to the original data:

```
Sub Macro2() ' ' Macro2 Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q ' 
    Set rngMyRange = Selection 
    ActiveCell = ActiveCell & "*1.9599" 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take the existing formula, enclose it in `()` brackets, and append a multiplication. This should preserve the cell references of your existing formula, though I've only really tested it on a couple of very simple formulas.

```
Sub MultiplyFomulaByPi()

    Dim factor As Double
    factor = 3.1415926

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection

    'Get old formula
    Dim oldFormula As String
    oldFormula = Mid(r.Formula, 2) 'removes the leading "=" sign

    'Assign new formula 
    r.Formula = "=(" & oldFormula & ")*" & factor

End Sub
```

Example, before and after:

[image]   [image]